# Want to pass parameter in bash file through php file

Tags: php, linux, bash, arguments

PHP code:

```
$number_server = 10;
exec("/bin/bash wrun.sh $number_server",$wuptime);
```

Bash script:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 for i in `seq echo $1`; do
     ssh /usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime
     ps -elf | grep httpd | wc -l
     free -       m;mpstat'
 done &

 pid=$!
 sleep 3
 kill -9 $pid && echo "not respond in give time"
```

In this I want to pass the argument `$number_server` to the bash script from the php file.

Comment: Have you tried to print $1 in shell script??

Comment: Please correct your bash script based on the results you get from http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq $1`; do
```